# What is frontend when creating a product attribute

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute

I want to know what is the use of frontend when creating a product attribute using installData or updateData.

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'sample_attribute',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
            'input' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Frontend means how an attribute should be rendered on frontend. You can find complete detail in dev docs that why each parameter / key is used while creating product attribute. Here is the url : https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/

Comment: I want to create like this https://nwdthemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/arrayserialized1.jpg on product page and save all the value in serialize and deserialize when open.

Answer (score 1):

The frontend and backend in installData refers to frontend model and backend model respectively.

You can define a class extending `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend` in case of frontend and `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend` in case of backend.

The functions mentioned in these abstract classes can be implemented in our own class to give various functionalities regarding backend and frontend.

For eg.  `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend`'s  `public function validate($object)` can be used to apply custom validation in admin.

Comment: I want to create like this nwdthemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/arrayserialized1.jpg on product page and save all the value in serialize and deserialize when open.